# Как дождаться завершения работы веб-установщика .net Framework?

Tags: c#

Как дождаться завершения работы веб-установщика .net framework 4.5.2?

Пробую так:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(file, Properties.Resources.NDP452_KB2901954_Web);    
var proc = Process.Start(file);    
proc.WaitForExit();
```

Но программа получает управление, хотя окно с информацией о том, что "Framework 4.5.2 или новее уже имеется" все еще висит.

Как я понимаю, это окно является частью другого процесса, а изначальный уже завершился.

На 10ке нет возможности проверить(не знаю как).

Как будет вести себя код, если фреймворка не будет? Дождется установки или как и сейчас - просто пойдет дальше?

Answer (score 0):

```
File.WriteAllBytes(file, Properties.Resources.NDP452_KB2901954_Web);
var proc = Process.Start(file);

proc.WaitForInputIdle();

proc.WaitForExit();
```

Помогло добавление WaitForInputIdle().